# What's the best practice to do something after some events all fired

Tags: javascript

For example, I want to tell user that everything is ready after a bunch of async initialization(they fire events when they are done), what's the best practice?

My solution is using a counter counting the number of events, and once the value of counter equal to total number of events, then I toast a message.

Comment: You 'toast' a message? And, while I've yet to experiment with them, would a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) be what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks David, that's helpful~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a definite number of events that will be fired, then I don't see the problem with using a counter for the events, as you suggested. That way you will know for certain that all of the events have been fired, and it's only slightly inefficient since it requires checking the count in every callback.

Otherwise, promises, which are "then'able" could work, e.g.:

```
var promises = [ asyncProcessOne(), asyncProcessTwo(), asyncProcessThree() ];

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(onFulfilled, onRejected) // run onFulfilled if process is successful
```